Angular Material Table - How to specify the width of a column
<mat-tab class="StatusTab" label="Status">
  <mat-table class="table mat-elevation-z10" [dataSource]="statusDetails">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Staff-id</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let staff">{{staff.staff_id}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let staff">{{staff.name}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container style="width: 10px;" matColumnDef="status">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let staff">{{staff.status}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let staff;columns:columns"></mat-row>
 </mat-table>
</mat-tab>

CSS:
.table {
    width: 100%;
    margin:50px;
}

.mat-column-id {
    width: 32px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

The default width is too long that it's scrollable to the right and I want to specify the width.
I tried to use .mat-column-COLUMNNAME but it is not working. But that only works if I use <table mat-table>.

You should also work with max-width CSS rule to force the maximum width of the column.
.mat-column-id {
  width: 32px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 32px;
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

It works thankyou @Yong

Hi @darshank, you are welcome. You may read the article: What should I do when someone answers my question?. Thanks.
